# How do I auto-select the text inside a textbox that is part of an AJAXContolToolkit Popup Control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

I've built an ASP User Control that implements the AJAX Control Toolkit PopupControlExtender.

It pops up a div containing a text box, and an OK/Cancel button. The idea is that the user can click a "rename" icon, which displays the popup with a message saying "Please enter the new name" and a text box with the old name already populated and highlighted, so that when the user starts to type, it immediately overwrites the old name, or the user can simply edit the existing name.

I can work out some simple Javascript to set the focus and select the text, but how do I get it to execute just as the popup is displayed? The text box is populated during an AJAX call back.

The code for my user control is quite large because it's doing a lot of stuff, so I won't post it unless anyone requests it.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: You can't add your code to the callback function, just after the text box is populated?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this... are you talking about a callback function part of the Popup control?

Comment: I think you really have to show relevant parts of your code, so we can see what you mean and give a better explanation.